# NoOptions cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, google-play-services

I am trying to put google play services in my game.

I have import BaseGameUtils project, when I add him to my workspace eclipse says:

```
 "NoOptions cannot be resolved to a type"
```

And:

```
 "The import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api.ApiOptions cannot be resolved"
```

It happens in the GameHelper class.

This is the only thing that it cannot resolve.
Some one have a solution for this?
I have tried all and I coudn't fins for some solutions.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: I see you have imported the BaseGameUtils project, but have you imported the GooglePlayServices project?

Comment: Yes, and I also create a refernce of it in BaseGameUtils.

Comment: Are you using the latest BaseGameUtils and GooglePlayServices?

BaseGameUtils: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/eclipse_compat/libraries

Comment: I downloaded again BaseGameUtils from your link, imported it and still it cannot resolve NoOptions. And how do I know if I use the latest GooglePlayServices?

Comment: Go to the manifest of the Google Play Services project. Im using the versionName 4.3.23 and things work just fine. It seems there is a 4.4 one that was just released in may: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Comment: Thank you for replaying!
I am also use version 4.3.23, How can I update my Google Play Services project to 4.4?

Comment: Just a wild guess - if you don't want to update your Google Play Services, you can try changing the **Project Build Target** to Google APIs of the appropriate API level. By default it usually is in Android x.x.

PS: To change this you might want to right click on the project and select Properties. You can find this in Android section.

Comment: you already see this?: http://stackanswers.com/questions/23849001/basegameutils-googleapiclient-apioptions-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle, make sure you have this in your dependencies

```
dependencies
    {
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+"
    }
```